# Verifying the user hasn't typed in the box within a certain time period

Tags: php, ajax

I am making a chat application with PHP and AJAX and I want to show a message if the user has been on the page for at least 1-2 minutes and hasn't typed anything in the chat box in the last 1-2 minutes.

I want to show a message in the chat box like in Yahoo: `[last message received 2-3 minutes ago]`

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of approach are you thinking to take towards this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code to show how you think the problem could be solved, and what problems you have encountered. Don't expect people to do your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) to periodically run a function that checks the value of the input, and compare it to the previous time you checked (which you would need to store).

If it hasn't changed, you can use an [XHR](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) to tell the server.

Comment: setTimeout would probably be better -- it sounds like he only wants something to happen when the text field has been empty for over 2 minutes after a message has been received. Just set a timeout when a message is received, and when it calls back, see if the textbox is empty

Answer (score 3):

You would probably use [setTimeout](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/).

Set a timeout when a new message is received. You create a callback function that will be called after the time has expired -- the function would write the message. When a message is received, the timeout would be cleared as described in that link.

To expand on this, you might want to set some kind of variable in the script when the user changes the textbox, and have the callback function check the variable (which would be cleared when a new message is received) -- that way, if a user receives a message, and changes their mind and deletes it, the message would not be displayed. but I'm not sure if that's the behavior you want.

If you want the message to change every so often, use [setInterval](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/), which will first draw the message, and then update the amount of time that has passed since the message was received. You could even combine them -- set the timeout to 3 minutes, and then from the callback from setTimeout, start an interval for every 1 minute. You might want to clear the interval and erase the message when a new message is received though, so you don't have these stale meaningless "message received 5 minutes ago" messages lying around in the conversation.